# Creating a Button on a waypoint

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I've created a Map App using the JXMapKit and used the waypoint class to create custom waypoints.
I need to know how can I add button functionality to graphics2D objects. is there a "Button" interface, or should I extend an existing button, or component class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved using a mouse-clicked action listener and check if the mouse click was a small (ie 5pixel) distance from the waypoint